# Keras LSTM training loss is increasing instantaneously in one epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am training an `LSTM` to predict a price chart. In order to do so I am arranging the data into 3D with a certain time window like 10 days to predict the next day.

I am not shuffling the data before splitting into training and testing. So the most recent data is used as testing. Is that a good idea with a stateless `LSTM`?

Secondly, during one epoch, the training is firstly decreasing but halfway through the epoch it is suddenly increased by an order of magnitude? what are the possible reasons for that happening? Is this normal behavior. I.e. is it a misconception of mine that loss in one epoch should constantly decrease?

I used Bayesian optimization to find the right hyperparameter and I am using `adam` optimizer with the default learning rate. And normalizing data between 0 and 1.